# Is there a terminal emulator like powershell or Windows Terminal, for Linux?

Tags: terminal, software-rec, terminal-emulator

Say what you will about Windows, but there are a couple of features of powershell that I found immensely helpful:

- Suggestions for autocompletion: If I type `cd my` then hit CTRL+SPACE, not only do I see the suggested folders starting with `my`, but I can navigate in a menu to select one of the alternatives.
- Hotkeys work like in a text editor (CTRL+C copies, CTRL+V pastes, holding SHIFT while arrowing selects text, etc)

I have installed powershell on my Linux machine. But obviously the hotkeys don't work because I am still just using gnome-terminal even if I open powershell.

So my question is: Is there a terminal emulator for Linux that have the same features as the powershell terminal for Windows?

Comment: Could you possibly mention what Linux you are using?

Comment: ctrl-C send SIGINT to the running process since "the beginning of time". TAB was used for completion since the 1960s. MS Windows command shell adapted TAB key for their completion. Now some people decide to do a similar thing with new key bindings and – hey! – why can't the old people change their habits to switch keys bindings? Strange request.

Comment: The learning curve isn't that steep; while one can connect the localhost with puTTY, if it has to be.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> are normally used to copy/paste text in the graphical Linux terminal.

For autocompletion you simply press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [zsh](https://www.howtogeek.com/362409/what-is-zsh-and-why-should-you-use-it-instead-of-bash/), that handles autocompletion differently to bash, with a list, that can be interacted with.

<strike>And also if you like powershell so much, why not [install it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2)?</strike>

Comment: The OP wrote: "I have installed powershell on my Linux machine. But obviously the hotkeys don't work because I am still just using gnome-terminal even if I open powershell."

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that. And I also don't understand why that would matter.

Comment: A colleague of mine just introduced me to "oh my zsh" (https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh), and the auto suggestions plugin and this soothes my desire for the autocompletion

Comment: This question asked for a **terminal emulator**. In Windows, a terminal emulator is provided alongside powershell. However only the **shell** is provided on other platforms.